# Market Place not working in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-luna, eclipse-marketplace

I have installed Eclipse Luna(4.4) on my system using the binary file and it is having the MPC plugin which is downloaded from the site :

```
http://download.eclipse.org/mpc/luna/
```

Still i am unable to find the Market Place in the Help tab, but in the

About Eclipse >> Installation Details >> Installed Software' , 'Marketplace Client' is visible.

Please help me how to Launch it.

Edit- Attaching the screenshot from Eclipse which shows the MarketPlace is installed, still it is not showing in Help Menu

[image]
[image]

Comment: make sure that your eclipse has internet access.

Comment: Yeah, the internet access is there and also have set the proxy settings, The plugin is already installed, just unable to launch it

Comment: Marketplace should be installed by default in Luna.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Go to ***Help/Install new software*** from the menu, select the Juno update site (**http://download.eclipse.org/releases/juno 'try this repository'**), and look for the Marketplace client it is in the General Purpose Tools category

Comment: Thanks a lot Tiko, it worked. It looks like the marketplace available at Luna site has some bugs due to which it is not visible in Help menu.

Comment: Yeah probably that's the case. Anyway happy to be helpful

Comment: Marketplace in Luna is not working properly when you search: you get an "unexpected exception" (Class not found).

Comment: It's good that this works but I clicked on Marketplace from Eclipse.org and ... http://marketplace.eclipse.org didn't load.  I expect there's some on-going bother.

Answer (score 1):

Either drag-and-drop the install URL from the Marketplace website to your Eclipse instance (the main toolbar is a good drop target), or open Help/Eclipse Marketplace... to start it. See also the [Marketplace documentation](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/marketplace-client-intro).

Comment: As mentioned in my previous comment, it is showing that MPC is already showing in Plugings tab

Comment: I did not mean the plugins tab. I said, select the Eclipse Marketplace... menu item from the Help menu.

Comment: I have attached the screenshot in the Question, for your reference.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I have the same component installed and its menu contribution is visible as well. I have only two ideas to check: (1) is anything visible in the Eclipse logs (open the Error Log view if not visible) and (2) maybe an uninstall-reinstall cycle would help.

Answer (score 0):

->open (your eclipse luna folder)-->configuration-->config
->open the config file with wordpad and add the below lines at the end.

org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4

->save the config file 
->Now restart the eclipse luna and try to access the market place.

Comment: Please, add some description to your answer and improve its format.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try update your Eclipse installation?

I had the same problem and I solved it selecting all updates from:

Help -> Check for Updates

I hope this helps.