# Eclipse luna crashed (Eclipse IDE closed abrubtly) during Eclipse Marketplace loading

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-luna

I installed JDK-1.8_20 and Eclipse Luna in Linux Mint 16. When I clicked Eclipse Marketplace form menu, Eclipse Luna crashed (Eclipse IDE closed abrubtly). I checked the following answers but those answers are not matched with my scenarios:

1. [Eclipse Marketplace hangs (Luna, Java8)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26069849/eclipse-marketplace-hangs-luna-java8)
2. [Market Place not working in Eclipse Luna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24772674/market-place-not-working-in-eclipse-luna)

Is it possible to resolve this issue?

**Update:**
I have added log from /workspace/.metadata/.log file:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.core.resources 2 10035 2014-10-13 20:32:16.558
!MESSAGE The workspace exited with unsaved changes in the previous session; refreshing workspace to recover changes.
!ENTRY org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration 2 0 2014-10-13 20:32:17.080
!MESSAGE Exception while setting up logging:org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
!STACK 0
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Comment: Please provide more information. Include a stack trace, error log, error message, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. I had to change a GTK theme to fix it.

Put following into the `~/.config/gtk-3.0/settings.ini` file:

```
[Settings]
gtk-theme-name = Adwaita
gtk-fallback-icon-theme = gnome
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related with both GTK2 and GTK3 starting in the same process.

```
the workaround is to use GTK2 for eclipse as well. This can be achieved in the following ways

1. add the following lines to eclipse.ini before -vmargs(recommended approach)
  --launcher.GTK_version
  2

2. set the environment variable SWT_GTK3 to 0 before launching eclipse. you need to do this every time you launch eclipse
```

Source: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438598#c16